# How to debug a hosted Service of iis (local) in visual Studio in same network

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis, service

I have A hosted Service like 
http://Loc090/MyHotelMyChoice/Food...

It is running in iis local .. now I have a second computer which is in same network (ios System) MAc mini .. ..

In this mac system my android application is running which have a service reference of my hosted Service
http://Loc090/MyHotelMyChoice/Food

So here I want ,  when I hit this service and call food method from mac ios system application .. it will go to my hosted service which hit to my open 
visual solution to debug point  ..

So that I can debug all the thing ..

Is there any way by which I can debug the hosted service calling ..

Please help me

Thank you all in advance ..